# Magnific Popup with Wordpress Image (php content)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, magnific-popup

My page content is dynamic `<?php the_content(); ?>`, and I cannot define an image's `a` class with html. So, I added with javascript: `$('.single-post img').parent('a').addClass("image-popup-no-margins");`

Although everything is loading properly, this did not work. Anybody know why?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/casslt07/jujpewz9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the addClass code before code for setting up Magnific Popup and it should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('img').parent('a').addClass("image-popup-no-margins");
    $('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: true,
        closeBtnInside: false,
        fixedContentPos: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default     margin from left and right side
        image: {
            verticalFit: true
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
        }
    });

 });
```

Comment: Ah, Just the order need to change, so it would load before the magicpopup code. So simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add class in after `anchor` tag `<a>`

```
class="image-popup-no-margins"
```

so code is

```
<a class="image-popup-no-margins" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg">
    <img class="aligncenter  wp-image-1054" src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg" height="75" width="107">
</a>
```

[Jsfiddle Preview](https://jsfiddle.net/abdulla_nilam/ww89v8m8/)

Comment: Thank you. Because my image is actually part of a php function `<?php the_content(); ?>` , I am unable to do that. The second image in the fiddle is undefine intentionally, to represent php.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, I discovered the developer has a way to implement this with `delegate: 'a'`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent-div').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
      closeOnContentClick: true,
        closeBtnInside: false,
        fixedContentPos: true,
        mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
        image: {
            verticalFit: true
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
        }
  });
});
```